# Java PDF libraries in GAE for enription

Tags: google-app-engine

We need get pdfs and encript them in Appengine (GAE).

We have tried to do it with itext, pdfjet and pdfbox they doesn`t work in appengine.

Somebody knows a library which works well on GAE?, or could help us to identify the problems with the other libraries to work on GAE?

Best Regards

Comment: Could you let us know what you tried exactly with PDF files and what did not work on GAE? Give some more details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a special version of iText, prepared for GAE - https://github.com/bedatadriven/appengine-export

It's based on old version of iText (last version under LGPL licence). But it works well, I don't have any problem.